# Bootstrap grid formatting - different devices

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am not the best html/css coder and I have this html which works fine on a desktop, but looks very poor on a phone.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row"><strong>Estimated # of Monthly XXXXXXXXs:</strong></div>
    <div class="row"><strong>Estimated Monthly Revenue Increase!!:</strong></div>
    <div class="row"><strong>Estimated Monthly XXXXXXXXXs Costs:</strong>  </div>
    <div class="row"><strong>Using XXXXXXXXX gives you:</strong></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div id="qrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><strong>
    <div id="howl">0</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div><strong>
    <div id="howt">$0.00</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div><strong>
    <div id="howa">$0.00</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div><strong>
    <div id="howri">$0.00</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div id="qint"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On a desktop, it comes out as:

```
Estimated # of Monthly Leads:         0
Estimated Monthly Revenue Increase:   $0.00
Estimated Monthly XXXXXXXX Costs:     $0.00
Using XXXXXXXXX gives you:            $0.00
```

But on a phone it displays as:

```
Estimated # of Monthly 
Leads:         
Estimated Monthly Revenue
Increase:   
Estimated Monthly XXXXXXXX
Costs:     
Using XXXXXXXXX gives you:            
0
$0.00
$0.00
$0.00
```

I could just use a single grid but I like that both columns are aligned. So how do I keep the same nice desktop formatting on a phone?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited. I need the phone formatting to look same as desktop.

Comment: Please add your HTML which you have tried to display above output

Comment: You could add `col-xs-n` class ,you have to adjust font size to get exact layout as desktop

Comment: @Anuresh. Thank you. I'm playing around with this as we speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zo7fx9p/3/)..

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
    <div class="row">
      <strong>Estimated # of Monthly XXXXXXXXs:</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <strong>Estimated Monthly Revenue Increase!!:</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <strong>Estimated Monthly XXXXXXXXXs Costs:</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <strong>Using ActiveLEAD gives you:</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div id="qrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><strong>
    <div id="howl">0</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div><strong>
    <div id="howt">$0.00</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div><strong>
    <div id="howa">$0.00</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div><strong>
    <div id="howri">$0.00</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div id="qint"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap 3 then make use of `col-xs-3` to align the way you want in the phone. Please follow the below code.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
  <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9">
    <div class="row"><strong>Estimated # of Monthly XXXXXXXXs:</strong></div>
    <div class="row"><strong>Estimated Monthly Revenue Increase!!:</strong></div>
    <div class="row"><strong>Estimated Monthly XXXXXXXXXs Costs:</strong>  </div>
    <div class="row"><strong>Using ActiveLEAD gives you:</strong></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div id="qrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3"><strong>
    <div id="howl">0</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div><strong>
    <div id="howt">$0.00</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div><strong>
    <div id="howa">$0.00</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div><strong>
    <div id="howri">$0.00</div></strong>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div id="qint"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```